# Blazor Wasm and FluentValidation with Localization

Tags: c#, localization, blazor, blazor-webassembly, fluentvalidation

In my razor file:

```
<EditForm id="@EditFromId" Model="@Entity" OnValidSubmit="Save">
    <FluentValidator TValidator="PersonalInformationValidator" />
```

In my `PersonalInformationValidator` class:

```cs
public PersonalInformationValidator(IStringLocalizer<ErrorResource> Loc)
{
    ClassLevelCascadeMode = CascadeMode.Continue;

    RuleFor(entity => entity.FatherName)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage(x=>Loc["Father-Name-Required"])
        .Length(3, 50).WithMessage(x => Loc["Father-Name-Length"]);
}
```

I get a compilation time error:

> Error CS1662  Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

and

> Error CS0310  'PersonalInformationValidator' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TValidator' in the generic type or method 'FluentValidator'

Tried to add this line to the Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<PersonalInformation>, PersonalInformationValidator>();
```

Also tried to create a parameterless contractor `PersonalInformationValidator`. It resolves the compile time error but the validator does not work.

I am using FluentValidation (11.4.0)

and this class on the client side:

```cs
public class FluentValidator<TValidator> : ComponentBase where TValidator : IValidator, new()
{
    private readonly static char[] separators = new[] { '.', '[' };
    private TValidator? validator;

    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext? EditContext { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (EditContext != null)
        {
            validator = new TValidator();
            var messages = new ValidationMessageStore(EditContext);
            EditContext.OnFieldChanged += (sender, eventArgs)
                => ValidateModel((EditContext?)sender, messages);

            EditContext.OnValidationRequested += (sender, eventArgs)
                => ValidateModel((EditContext?)sender, messages);
        }
    }

    private void ValidateModel(EditContext? editContext, ValidationMessageStore messages)
    {
        if (editContext != null)
        {

            var context = new ValidationContext<object>(editContext.Model);
            var validationResult = validator?.Validate(context);
            messages.Clear();
            if (validationResult != null)
            {
                foreach (var error in validationResult.Errors)
                {
                    var fieldIdentifier = ToFieldIdentifier(editContext, error.PropertyName);
                    messages.Add(fieldIdentifier, error.ErrorMessage);
                }
                editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private static FieldIdentifier ToFieldIdentifier(EditContext editContext, string propertyPath)
    {
        var obj = editContext.Model;

        while (true)
        {
            var nextTokenEnd = propertyPath.IndexOfAny(separators);
            if (nextTokenEnd < 0)
            {
                return new FieldIdentifier(obj, propertyPath);
            }

            var nextToken = propertyPath.Substring(0, nextTokenEnd);
            propertyPath = propertyPath.Substring(nextTokenEnd + 1);

            object newObj;
            if (nextToken.EndsWith("]"))
            {

                nextToken = nextToken.Substring(0, nextToken.Length - 1);
                var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Item");
                var indexerType = prop?.GetIndexParameters()[0].ParameterType;
                var indexerValue = Convert.ChangeType(nextToken, indexerType);
                newObj = prop?.GetValue(obj, new object[] { indexerValue });
            }
            else
            {
                var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(nextToken);
                if (prop == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not find property named {nextToken} on object of type {obj.GetType().FullName}.");
                }
                newObj = prop?.GetValue(obj);
            }

            if (newObj == null)
            {
                return new FieldIdentifier(obj, nextToken);
            }

            obj = newObj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know which package / Fluent Validation version that you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the constraint with parameterless constructor `new()` from the `TValidator` constraint.
2. Get the `IStringLocalizer<ErrorResource>` service from the DI.
3. With `Activator.CreateInstance()` create `TValidator` instance with provide the `Loc` as parameter.

```cs
public class FluentValidator<TValidator> : ComponentBase
    where TValidator : IValidator
{
    private readonly static char[] separators = new[] { '.', '[' };
    private TValidator? validator;

    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext? EditContext { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    IStringLocalizer<ErrorResource> Loc { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (EditContext != null)
        {
            validator = (TValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TValidator), new object[] { Loc });

            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

> Demo

[image]